# Symfony2 Services Circular dependency?

Tags: php, symfony, behat

**UPDATE:** The problem wasn't on the server code, but on the Behat execution environment.

I'm developing a Symfony2 project, and somehow, after many months of development I've introduced a bug which crashes the entire application and outputs the following error message:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 289
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php:423
PHP   3. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->createCommand() /var/www/main_api/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:96
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:138
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
PHP   8. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  10. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  11. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  12. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
PHP  13. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
PHP  14. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
PHP  15. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  16. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  17. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
PHP  18. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490

[...]

PHP  93. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
PHP  94. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
PHP  95. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
PHP  96. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  97. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
PHP  98. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
PHP  99. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:469

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 289

Call Stack:
    0.0010     412904   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php:0
    0.4579    3401528   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/behat.php:423
    0.4900    3747408   3. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
    0.4900    3747392   4. Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->createCommand() /var/www/main_api/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:96
    1.7987    7874496   5. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php:138
    1.7987    7876432   6. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
    1.7991    7879072   7. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
    1.7991    7879560   8. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    1.7991    7880392   9. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    1.7991    7880880  10. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.0948   14305112  11. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.0948   14305200  12. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
    3.0948   14305496  13. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
    3.0949   14306208  14. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
    3.0949   14306696  15. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1179   14383304  16. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1179   14383416  17. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
    3.1180   14383760  18. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490

[...]    

    3.1192   14540512  79. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
    3.1193   14540952  80. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
    3.1193   14541440  81. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1193   14542096  82. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1193   14542144  83. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1019
    3.1193   14542584  84. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
    3.1193   14543072  85. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1193   14543728  86. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1193   14543816  87. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
    3.1194   14544112  88. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
    3.1244   14552552  89. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->callMethod() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:975
    3.1244   14553384  90. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1165
    3.1244   14553872  91. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1244   14554464  92. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1244   14554568  93. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
    3.1245   14554896  94. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:490
    3.1246   14555512  95. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:943
    3.1246   14556000  96. array_map() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1247   14557184  97. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->resolveServices() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1015
    3.1247   14557280  98. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:1017
    3.1247   14557424  99. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /var/www/main_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:469


Process finished with exit code 255
```

I think this is because a circular dependency between services, is it possible? If that's the case, is there a systematic way to find circular dependencies between services in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, it wasn't a problem in my code, but in the Behat execution environment.

I had to change the max nesting level with the following entry in the `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file (I'm on Debian):

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```